# How to access res.locals on client-side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm attempting to pass `req.user` details to my client-side Angular code by using `res.locals` in my Express route:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');

var player = function(req, res) {
  res.locals.player = req.player;
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../assets', 'index.html'));
};

module.exports = {
  player: player
};
```

The HTML renders as expected, but I'm not sure how to access `res.locals.player` now.

Comment: It's a bit unclear where you keep your angularjs code, in your example you just send plain HTML file and do not use any template engines for rendering your pages, like jade. So the suggestion rather depends on it. In principle you can create GET route in your express app which will return player as JSON object to angularjs.